# JavaScript function to find even numbers by given step

Tags: javascript, function, numbers, find

### I'm trying to write a function in JavaScript to complete this exercise. I've got a function written that will display the even numbers. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the function to display the even numbers by a step like in the example.

Allow a user to enter a starting number an ending number and a step value into three textboxes on a page. A button will be present that when clicked should output all the even numbers between the start and end value.
[illustration example of exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWzwQ.png)

### In the example above the user has entered 4 and 20 as the start and end, respectively and set the step to 3. This means the numbers 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, and 19 were considered, but only 4, 10, and 16 were displayed.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
   function showEvens () {
   var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
   var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
   var step = document.getElementById("step").value;
   var evenNums = "<br>Even Numbers:<br>";

   for(i=start; i<=end; i++) {
   if (i%2 == 0) {
   evenNums += i + "<br>";
   }
   }
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = evenNums;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be incrementing `i` by `step` (`i += step` rather than `i++`) in your `for` loop:

```js
function showEvens() {
  var start = 4;
  var end = 20;
  var step = 3;
  var evenNums = "<br>Even Numbers:<br>";

  for (i = start; i <= end; i+=step) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      evenNums += i + "<br>";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = evenNums;
}

showEvens();
```

```html
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Your codepen is not working because `value` returns a string. You should be using `valueAsNumber` to get it in integer form:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Display Events</h1>
  <script>
    function showEvens() {
      var start = document.getElementById("start").valueAsNumber;
      var end = document.getElementById("end").valueAsNumber;
      var step = document.getElementById("step").valueAsNumber;
      var evenNums = "<br>Even Numbers:<br>";

      for (i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          evenNums += i + "<br>";
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = evenNums;
    }
  </script>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Starting Number:</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="start" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ending Number:</td>
      <td> <input type="number" id="end" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Step:</td>
      <td> <input type="number" id="step" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="showEvens()" value="View Even Numbers" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="result"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Quick follow-up: when I run the code, I'm not seeing the results print out. I'm not seeing where my error is. https://codepen.io/kurt-reynolds/pen/bGWZyEB

Comment: @KurtReyn I've updated my answer to fix your codepen.